# How can I get array length in pymongo?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I watched this post [How can I get the length of a MongoDb array field?](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-can-i-get-the-length-of-a-mongodb-array-field-solved/11477)

I tried these codes:

```
results=db.posts.find()
results[0].comments.length
```

I am sure the post and comments exist. But it does not work. It will return an error:

```
AttributeError: 'comments' object has no attribute 'length'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: This part of codes is using in Jinja2. And there is a filter to count the array length in jinja2. It is {{results[0].comments|length}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pymongo returns documents as dicts.  find() returns an array of dicts.  You need:

```
len(results[0]['comments'])
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Jinja2 allows you to access dict items as attributes so you should be able to  `{{ results[0].comments | length }}`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the length of the array, do:

```
result = client.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            'my_array_length': {'$size': '$my_array'}
        }
    }
])
```